# How do I make sure only logged-in users can acces a page?

Tags: php

I'm really struggling with the whole 'only logged-in users can view this page'. Php is new to me and I can't seem to figure this out. Maybe this is a dumb question or my code is not right, but I'm really trying to figure this out.

login.php:

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    function is_logged() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) return $_SESSION['username'];
        else return false;
    }

    if (is_logged()) {
        $user_id = is_logged();

        do_something($user_id);
    } else {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //form submitted
            //check login and password, if they are correct, do this:
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username_from_database;
            //if not correct
            unset($_SESSION['username']);

            header('Location: welcome.php'); //refresh page
        } else {
            //show login form with button named 'submit'
        }
    }
?>



<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<!-- The HTML login form -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
<?php
} else {
    require_once("db_const.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * from GEBRUIKERS WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Logged in successfully</p>";
        // do stuffs
    }



    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // Output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $_SESSION['+login_user']=$user; // Initializing Session
        header("location: welcome.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
    }
} 


else {
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}

mysqli_close($conn); // Closing Connection

}
?>      
</body>
</html>
```

Welcome.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<!--Header wordt opgehaald-->
</head>
<?php
    require "header2.php"
?>

<?php   
$servername =   "localhost";
$username   =   ""; 
$password   =   "";
$database = "";
//  Create  connection  
$conn   =   mysqli_connect($servername, $username,  $password, $database);  
//  Check   connection  
if  (!$conn)    {   
                die("Connection failed: "   .   mysqli_connect_error());    
}   
echo "Connected successfully";
?>

<body>

<?php   
//Perform queries
$sql = "SELECT acteur_voornaam, acteur_tussenvoegsel, acteur_achternaam, acteur_geboortedatum FROM FILM_ACTEURS";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//Films
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table style='border: solid 1px grey; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top:50px;'><th>Voornaam</th><th>Tussenvoegsel</th><th>Achternaam</th><th>Geboortedatum</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["acteur_voornaam"] . "<td>" . $row["acteur_tussenvoegsel"]. "<td> " . $row["acteur_achternaam"]. "<td> " . $row["acteur_geboortedatum"] . "" . "</td></tr>";
    }
        echo "<table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?> 
    </body>
    <?php
//Footer wordt opgehaald

    include "footer.php"

?>


    </html>
```

Comment: on each page on top call `is_logged()`.And if it returns false redirect to login .php

Comment: **Warning:** You're open to `sql injection`, please read [how to use prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). `sql injection` means that you are open for attacks, they can acces your database and manupulate it. **Another warning** hash your passwords, it is **not** safe to save plain into a database. Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` to encrypt your passwords.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I was open to sql injection. Right now it's a school assignment.

Comment: @Nienke Yes, I can see that. But, in your login function, you `unset()` the `$_SESSION['username']` immediatly after you set it... This causes your issue with the other answers here.

Comment: I'm going to remove it. Will this solve it? I'm sorry, this is just new to me, so it takes some time to understand it.

Comment: @Nienke Yes, it should. Or there is another issue I overlooked.

Comment: Not sure. I removed it, but stay stuck at the inlog page. It doesn't take me to the next page.

Comment: @Nienke Yes, I'm sorry but your code is a total mess I just realised. I would ask you to move into chat, as it will take a bit more then just a simple answer. [Here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141885/login-issue) is the room.

Comment: I know, haha. I can't talk with you via chat, since my reputation isn't 20...

Answer (score 0):

session_start(); and checking with is_logged(); must be included in all member only pages, there is another reason your code is not working, and that is you are not clearing the session variable after logout, so your browser logs you in automatically

Comment: @Nienke `unset($_SESSION["loggedIn");`

Comment: I also believe that the issue is that it's cleared *right* after it's set... just *mayybbeee*.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Within your login functionality create a session variable inside successful  login block like:

```
$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
```

Now on every page, where logged-in is required to access the page put the following check:

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && ($_SESSION['loggedIn'] != true) )
{
    // redirect the user to login screen if the session variable is not set and its value is not true
    header('location: login.php');
}
```

**Note:** To access the session you have to put `session_start()` on each page, and it must be the first line.

Answer (score 0):

First create a page called `session.php` which you have to include in all the pages

```
<?php
    session_start();

    function is_logged() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) return $_SESSION['username'];
        else return false;
    }

    if (is_logged()) {
        $user_id = is_logged();

        do_something($user_id);
    } else {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //form submitted
            //check login and password, if they are correct, do this:
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username_from_database;
            //if not correct
            unset($_SESSION['username']);

            header('Location: welcome.php'); //refresh page
        } else {
            //show login form with button named 'submit'
        }
    }
?>
```

Second: include the `session.php` page in all the pages. This will check for session or redirect to login page.

in Welcome page: `Welcome.php` on the top of the page include `session.php` like:

```
<?php
inlcude 'session.php';
?>
```

Do necessary changes in `session.php` file if required.

NOTE: you can give any name to `session.php` file.

Comment: I'm trying that, but it's quite difficult for a first time.

Comment: How is this good pratice, or an answer to the problem? It doesn't explain anything towards the problem, or solve it, for that matter....

Answer (score 0):

Try with isset function in php. put the bellow code after session start in the welcome.php file.

```
if(!(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != '')){
    header ("Location: login.php");
}else{
    header ("Location: welcome.php");
}
```

This redirect on login page if the session 'username' has not set. if the session already initialized then redirect to the welcome.php.

Comment: This brought me back to the login page, but now when I want to login, I just stay on the login page.

Comment: apply same condition in the login page too and make sure session started or not. you can check with <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, why would you put this same condition in the login page? You also clearly missed that she has a function `is_logged()` that makes it easier. If everything would go correctly, it shouldn't redirect to the login page. So adding it to the login page, isn't going to change *anything*.

Comment: So, how is it fixed? I don't really understand anymore.

Comment: @Nienke this was to the answer poster's comment, his answer *should* be correct, but his comment was nonesense, which I pointed out. Your code sufferd the `unset()` after the the set issue I pointed out, that is why you are immediatly redirected, as the `$_SESSION["username"]` was *not* set anymore.